# Save toggle text to cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have the following script that toggles the classes of two divs on click, and swithes the text on the trigger element. The toggle states are saved to cookies on and are maintained on page refresh. I dont know how to save the toggle text state to a cookie also. any help would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#secondaryfilter').toggleClass('no-filters', $.cookie('currentToggle') === 'on');
    $('#mymain').toggleClass('wide', $.cookie('currentToggleb') === 'on');
});
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.toggle-filters').on('click', function (e) {
        var txt = $("#secondaryfilter").is(':visible') ? '+ Show Filters' : '- Hide   Filters';
        $(".toggle-filters").text(txt);
        $("#secondaryfilter").toggleClass("no-filters");
        $('#mymain').toggleClass("wide");
        $.cookie('currentToggle', $("#secondaryfilter").hasClass('no-filters') ? 'on' : 'off');
        $.cookie('currentToggleb', $("#mymain").hasClass('wide') ? 'on' : 'off');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have cookie support built in. If you grabbed that sample code from somewhere you will also need to include the cookie plugin:

- https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

When you set the cookie in lines like these:

```
$.cookie('currentToggle', $("#secondaryfilter").hasClass('no-filters')?'on':'off' );
```

You are just creating a session cookie. This means that the browser will throw the cookie away when you close it. If you want this to be persisted next time they come back then you need to add in an expiry date like:

```
var currentToggle = $("#secondaryfilter").hasClass('no-filters')?'on':'off');
$.cookie('currentToggle', currentToggle, { expires: 7 });
```

Other than that I can't see any problem with your code, although I am wondering if you worded your question correctly as these two lines seem to contradict each other:

1. The toggle states are saved to cookies on and are maintained on page refresh.
2. I dont know how to save the toggle text state to a cookie also.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I have the jquery-cookie installed and my div states are stored and display correctly when the page is refreshed. You are right however the question was not worded correctly as I cannot get the text state to store and display correctly when the page is refreshed. Basically I need to figure out how to create a cookie to capture the current text and call it back on refresh

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with the following code, if anyone has anyway that the following could be improved I would love to see it. I would give an explanation but I am just learning and I feel my terminology may just confuse others.

Thanks to @rtpHarry for the response, I now know the difference between a session cookie and how to store a cookie for a given length of time even if the browser is closed, which I am sure will come in handy in the future.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {    
$('#secondaryfilter').toggleClass('no-filters', $.cookie('currentToggle') === 'on');
$('#mymain').toggleClass('wide', $.cookie('currentToggleb') === 'on');
var mytxt = $.cookie('txt');

if (mytxt === '- Hide Filters') {
$(".toggle-filters").text('+ Show Filters');
    } else {
$(".toggle-filters").text('- hide Filters');
    }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.toggle-filters').on('click', function(e) {  

var txt = $("#secondaryfilter").is(':visible') ? '+ Show Filters' : '- Hide Filters';
$(".toggle-filters").text(txt);

$("#secondaryfilter").toggleClass("no-filters");
    $('#mymain').toggleClass("wide");
    $.cookie('currentToggle', $("#secondaryfilter").hasClass('no-filters')?'on':'off' );
    $.cookie('currentToggleb', $("#mymain").hasClass('wide')?'on':'off' );
     $.cookie('txt', $("#secondaryfilter").is(':visible') ? '+ Show Filters' : '- Hide Filters');

e.preventDefault();
});
});
```